# Trying to iterate over a mongodb cursor twice - failing

Tags: php, mongodb

I am executing a query against my mongodb database... and then in two separate spots in my front end logic, I need to iterate through the results to extract / show different information.

**Problem**

The second time I try to iterate through, I get the following error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\LogicException: Cursors
>   cannot yield multiple iterators in
>   /var/www/localhost/htdocs/widgets/exception_details.php:46
>   Stack trace: #0

**Backend Code**

Here's the logic to query the database in my model:

```
    try{
        $id = new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId($docid);
        $filter = ['_id' => $id];
        $options = [];
        $query = new \MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
        $rows = $m->executeQuery('widgets.play_summary', $query);
        return $rows;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Exception:'. $e->getMessage();
        return false;
    }
```

**Front End Logic**

Here's the logic that attempts the iteration.

First time:

```
foreach ($rows as $id=>$value) {
        if ( count($value->unreachable_servers > 0) ) {
            foreach($value->unreachable_servers as $key=>$value) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>$value</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
 }
```

And then later, I try to do this:

```
$it = new IteratorIterator($rows);  //line 46
$it->rewind();  
foreach ($rows as $id=>$value) {
    if ( count($value->failed_plays > 0) ) { 
            foreach($value->failed_plays as $key=>$value) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>$value</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
            }
    }
 }
```

Additional Information

Commenting out the following lines gives the exact same error, but just on line 48 instead of line 46:

```
$it = new IteratorIterator($rows);
$it->rewind();
```

Any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

As a test, I changed the front end code to use rewind and next like this:

```
$it = new \IteratorIterator($rows);
$it->rewind(); 
//foreach ($rows as $id=>$value) {
while($value = $it->current()) {
        if ( count($value->unreachable_servers > 0) ) {
            foreach($value->unreachable_servers as $key=>$value) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>$value</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
  $it->next();
 }
```

And for the second loop:

```
$it = new IteratorIterator($rows);
$it->rewind();  
//foreach ($rows as $id=>$value) { 
while($value = $it->current()) {
    if ( count($value->failed_plays > 0) ) { 
            foreach($value->failed_plays as $key=>$value) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>$value</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
            }
    }
    $it->next();
 }
```

I get the same results.  It works the first time but the second time it bombs with the same error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cursor cannot be iterated twice. Fetch it into array, if it fits into memory:

```
    $rows = $m->executeQuery('widgets.play_summary', $query);
    return $rows->toArray();
```

**UPDATE**

Since the answer still attracts attention 5 years later, there was https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHPC-1691 to implement full `Iterator` interface, not only `Traversable`.

The implementation does not resolve OPs issue tho.

Technically https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-cursor.php does have the `rewind` method, but it throws an exception **Cursors cannot rewind after starting iteration** when called after first document was received: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/blob/0960a204b3b60f8a80375abb6390735b95c821f1/src/MongoDB/Cursor.c#L333

Comment: Then why do they give you a rewind method?  I'm giving your answer a try right now... but just thought I'd ask.

Comment: **they**? It is you, who are trying to wrap cursor with iterator.

Comment: Um ... so if you look at the documentation, it explicitly refers to a rewind method.  http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-cursor.php

Comment: If you are referring to the comment http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-cursor.php#118824, it is not a documentation by any means. Documentation is everything above "User Contributed Notes". Everything else on the page should be treated as an opinion of someone in the Internet. For the sake of sanity don't blindly trust user-contributed content anywhere in the web. Test it. Cursor implements `Traversable` - no more. There is no way to rewind it.